# regex unicode characters

Tags: python, regex

The following regex working online but not working in python code and shows no matches:
https://regex101.com/r/lY1kY8/2

s=re.sub(r'\x.+[0-9]',' ',s)

required:

re.sub(r'\x.+[0-9]* ',' ',r'cats\xe2\x80\x99 faces')

Out[23]: 'cats faces'

basically wanted to remove the unicode special characters `"\xe2\x80\x99"`

Comment: If you want to match these 3 Unicode characters, use `ur'[\xe2\x80\x99]'` regex with `search`. `re.search(ur'[\xe2\x80\x99]',u'cats\xe2\x80\x99 faces')` Does it work?

Comment: @stribizhev no all charac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another option that doesn't require regex, you could instead remove the unicode characters by removing anything not listed in [`string.printable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.printable)

```
>>> import string
>>> ''.join(i for i in 'cats\xe2\x80\x99 faces' if i in string.printable)
'cats faces'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print re.findall(r'\\x.*?[0-9]* ',r'cats\xe2\x80\x99 faces')
                                 ^^
```

Use `raw mode` flag.Use `findall` as `match` starts matching from beginning

```
print re.sub(ur'\\x.*?[0-9]+','',r'cats\xe2\x80\x99 faces')
```

with `re.sub`

```
s=r'cats\xe2\x80\x99 faces'
print re.sub(r'\\x.+?[0-9]*','',s)
```

EDIT:

The correct way would be to decode to `utf-8` and then apply regex.

```
s='cats\xe2\x80\x99 faces'
\xe2\x80\x99 is U+2019 
print re.sub(u'\u2019','',s.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: how to use that in substitution?

Comment: s=re.sub(r'\\x.+[0-9]',' ',s)

Comment: what if its variable?

Comment: no the string comes from a list in a function  s=r'cats\xe2\x80\x99 faces' is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Assume you use Python 2.x

```
>>> s = 'cats\xe2\x80\x99 f'
>>> len(s), s[4]
(9, 'â')
```

Means chars like `\xe2` is with 1 length, instead 3. So that you cannot match it with `r'\\x.+?[0-9]*'` to match it.

```
>>> s = '\x63\x61\x74\x73\xe2\x80\x99 f'
>>> ''.join([c for c in s if c <= 'z'])
'cats f'
```

Help this help a bit.